# Repeating UIButton animation and change background

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work?:

```
//Changing the Images
- (void) squareOneColour {
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(5);
    [self.squareOne setBackgroundImage:[self.colorArray objectAtIndex:r] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

//Moving buttons
- (void) squareOneMover {
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(3);

    [self.squareOne setHidden:NO];
    CGPoint originalPosition = self.squareOne.center;
    originalPosition.y = -55;

    [self.squareOne setCenter:originalPosition];
    CGPoint position = self.squareOne.center;
    position.y += 760;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:r + 3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         [self.squareOne setCenter:position];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL complete) {
                         if (complete) {
                             [self squareOneColour];
                             [self squareOneMover];
                         }
                     }
    ];
}
```

I am trying to get a `UIButton` to animate down the screen and when the animation is finished, for it to repeat but with a different background. The code above seems it should work but the second animation is never completed. (The `UIButton` is animated once, then everything stops). I have tried putting the code shown below (into the completion block), with an outside `NSUInteger` method creating a random number for r but it never works. But it does work when I replace r with a different number, like 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. After playing around with it, I found that the function I wanted the `UIButton` to do was only fit for a `UIImageView`. I guess I'll have to make an invisible button over the `UIImageView`

Comment: That has nothing do with it. Nothing in your code doesn't work in a UIButton. I tried it and it works fine (with my changes, of course).

Comment: And a button over an image view is silly. If you want tappability, use a gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You're stepping on your own feet. Step out to the next cycle of the runloop and all will be well:

```
[self squareOneColour];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self squareOneMover];
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Can you explain what this does?